# Best way to verify a BST in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I just started learning about trees and I wrote code to verify weather a tree is a BST or not and I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it than the current way that I am doing it. They way that I am doing it right now is that I am push all the values in each node into a stack than going through that stack to check if each value is less than the previous value. I feel like right now the runtime of the code is too high as well as the time complexity.

```
    // this code is to check if a binary tree is a BST

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 256

int A[MAX_SIZE];
int top;

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
}node;

node* Insert(node* root, int data);
void Inorder(node* root);
node* GetNewNode(int data);

void Push(int x){
    A[++top] = x;
}

void Pop(){
    top--;
}

int Top(){
    return A[top];
}

int main(void){
    int data, x, lastValue;
    int BST;
    node* root = NULL;
    printf("how many elements would you like to be in the tree\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        scanf("%i", &data);
        root = Insert(root, data);
    }
    Inorder(root);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        x = Top();
        if(i >= 1){
            if(top < 0){
                break;
            }
            if(lastValue > x){
                BST = 1;
            }
            else{
                BST = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        lastValue = x;

        Pop();
    }
    if(!BST){
        printf("not a BST\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("BST\n");
    }
}

node* Insert(node* root, int data){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data <= root->data){
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else{
        root->right= Insert(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}

node* GetNewNode(int data){
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void Inorder(node* root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    Inorder(root->left);
    Push(root->data);
    Inorder( root->right);
}
```

Comment: I'd expect the check to traverse the tree in any order (but pre-order is perhaps simplest), and the checking would ensure that the left child pointer is null or the left node value is less than (or equal to?) the current node, and the right node pointer is null or the right node value is greater than (or equal to?) the current node, identifying the problem if the condition is not met, and traversing down the left tree and right tree as appropriate.  Wouldn't that be simpler?  You can decide whether to continue the search after finding a first problem or whether to stop immediately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not sure if that is complete. Trees which are not a BST could also satisfy the condition. What we need is an in-order traversal and check for ascending.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Show me a tree that satisfies the condition I gave that isn't a BST.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `[[[0], 1, [4]], 2, [5]]`, middle being the value

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Will you able to find for 4 in this? You will go the right from root when you compare 4 with 2. I am not looking for balance

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Suffering from brain-rot over here.  Yes, I see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
   and a pointer to right child */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

int isBSTUtil(struct node* node, int min, int max);

/* Returns true if the given tree is a binary search tree 
 (efficient version). */
int isBST(struct node* node) 
{ 
  return(isBSTUtil(node, INT_MIN, INT_MAX)); 
} 

/* Returns true if the given tree is a BST and its 
   values are >= min and <= max. */
int isBSTUtil(struct node* node, int min, int max) 
{ 
  /* an empty tree is BST */
  if (node==NULL) 
     return 1;

  /* false if this node violates the min/max constraint */ 
  if (node->data < min || node->data > max) 
     return 0; 

  /* otherwise check the subtrees recursively, 
   tightening the min or max constraint */
  return
    isBSTUtil(node->left, min, node->data-1) &&  // Allow only distinct values
    isBSTUtil(node->right, node->data+1, max);  // Allow only distinct values
} 

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
  struct node* node = (struct node*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node);
}

/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
  struct node *root = newNode(4);
  root->left        = newNode(2);
  root->right       = newNode(5);
  root->left->left  = newNode(1);
  root->left->right = newNode(3); 

  if(isBST(root))
    printf("Is BST");
  else
    printf("Not a BST");

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use an extra data structure to verify is something is a binary search tree. What @Jonathan Leffer suggested in the comments is almost correct (it misses a very important edge case), and it does not fully check your binary search tree for optimal structure.

A binary search tree is, as the name suggests, a tree that essentially implements binary search with its structure. This means that when you traverse the tree, you want to make sure it is "sorted" (which I'll define in a bit), and make sure it is balanced. This will ensure that your binary search tree actually runs search in O(log n) time.

First of all, you need to check for sortedness. This is easiest to do by not allowing duplicates: in this case, most of you need to do is traverse the tree, checking at each node that the left and right children are less than and greater than (respectively, and if they exist), the current node. This is mostly correct, and will never cause a logic error if your insert and new methods function correctly. But if they don't, you could get a case like this:

```
        12
       /  \
      8    95 
     / \
    7   13
```

You'll notice that this "binary search tree" meets all of our requirements so far, but isn't actually a bst. It won't return the correct value when 13 is searched for (It will say that 13 is not in the tree). To correct for this, you'll need to keep track of the limiting value (12 in this case), and compare it to all values that should be smaller than it, but might not be in practice.

Then, we need to deal with balance. At this point, we have ensured that any bst will be correct, and if that is enough for you, then feel free to stop reading. However, avoiding this could create a big issue with runtime, and you may want to read on if you want a *real* bst.

Balance is a big issue with binary search trees. Consider this tree:

```
  12
    \
     13
       \
        14
          \ 
           15
             \
              16
```

This is a valid tree given our rules, but it is equivalent to a linked list, meaning insertion will run in O(n) time, exactly what a bst is supposed to avoid!

This can be avoided with another simple rule: No "side" of a bst node can have a "height" greater than one more of the other side.

To understand this rule, we need to understand side and height. Side refers to the right and left children of a given node, and all of their children. The height is the number of layers of children, defined recursively as the maximum of the height of each of a node's children plus 1, where the base case is a null node, which has a height of 0.

At this point, you have a coherent definition for balance, but how do you keep it when you insert things. For any given insertion, you might unbalance a tree!

Because this post is rambling on, I'll just spill the beans: given that the tree was balanced before the insertion, rotate the lowest unbalanced node in the direction opposite the unbalance. In the case that this still yields an unbalanced tree (because this is a case), rotate the unbalanced side once in the direction opposite your attempted rotation. This will require 4 cases when you actually program it out.

I know this was a bit of a information dump, but not using bst's correctly could lead to all sorts of trouble. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

A simple condition that the BST follows is that - In the inorder traversal, the elements will be ascending order.

And any tree that follows this is a BST. (maybe balanced or not, but I don't think that is what you need).

This is the simple code to check the inorder traversal

(assuming the tree contains only positive element, but that limitation can be easily removed)

```
int check(Node *node, int last) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return last;
    int left = check(node->left, last);
    if (left == -1)
        return -1;
    if (left > node->val)
        return -1;
    return check(node->right, node->val);
}
```

Then you call check(root, 0). It will return `-1` if it is not a BST. Else it will return the largest number in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

In order traversal can be done iteratively by changing the links in a tree (twice, once to set leaf nodes right link to successor node, again to restore it back to null). The algorithm is called Morris traversal. Most implementations of Morris traversal functions scan entire tree, rather than return links to nodes in order. The example code below is called with a pointer to the root node, and each call returns a pointer to node in traversal order. In this example part of the logic is in main(), where a subsequent call to the traversal function uses the the last returned node's right pointer as a parameter. This could be implemented in a second function that follows the right pointer and then calls the main traversal function.

```
/* mrstrv2.c - morris traversal of binary tree */
/* MorrisTraversal returns a set of pointers to nodes */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* binary tree node */
typedef struct BTNODE_
{
    struct BTNODE_* left;
    struct BTNODE_* right;
    int data;
}BTNODE;

/* traverse binary tree without stack */
/* initial input parameter is pointer to root */
/* predecessor of cur is largest value < cur */
/* predecessor of cur = cur->left->right->right->right ... */
BTNODE * MorrisTraversal(BTNODE *cur)
{
BTNODE *pre;
    if(cur == NULL)
        return(NULL);
    while(cur != NULL){
        /* if left end of branch, return */
        if(cur->left == NULL)
            return(cur);
        /* advance pre to predecessor of cur */
        pre = cur->left;
        while(pre->right != NULL && pre->right != cur)
            pre = pre->right;
        /* if right end of branch, change pre->right = cur */
        /*  and advance cur left */
        if(pre->right == NULL){
            pre->right = cur;
            cur = cur->left;
        /* else back at cur, so restore pre->right = NULL */
        /*  and return */
        } else {
            pre->right = NULL;
            return(cur);
        }
    }
    return(NULL);
}

BTNODE* newbtNode(int data)
{
BTNODE* btNode = (BTNODE*) malloc(sizeof(BTNODE));
    btNode->left = NULL;
    btNode->right = NULL;
    btNode->data = data;
    return(btNode);
}

int main()
{
/* create a binary search tree */
BTNODE *root = newbtNode(8);
BTNODE *cur;
    root->left                = newbtNode( 4);
    root->left->left          = newbtNode( 2);
    root->left->left->left    = newbtNode( 1);
    root->left->left->right   = newbtNode( 3);
    root->left->right         = newbtNode( 6);
    root->left->right->left   = newbtNode( 5);
    root->left->right->right  = newbtNode( 7);
    root->right               = newbtNode(12);
    root->right->left         = newbtNode(10);
    root->right->left->left   = newbtNode( 9);
    root->right->left->right  = newbtNode(11);
    root->right->right        = newbtNode(14);
    root->right->right->left  = newbtNode(13);
    root->right->right->right = newbtNode(15);
    /* traverse the tree in order, one node at a time */
    /* note cur is advanced to cur->right with each iteration */
    for(cur = root; cur; cur = cur->right){
        cur = MorrisTraversal(cur);
        printf("%2d ", cur->data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the idea here is to transerver in order in constant space. I am not sure if OP has that requirement (since he explicitly uses a stack). A recursive solution in that case would be far easier for one to understand.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - The issue with a recursive solution is the same as I mentioned in my answer, a single call to the function scans the entire tree. My answer shows an alternative where the function returns pointers to nodes one at a time in order, allowing the calling code to perform the desired in order operations, (in this case, the goal is to check for ascending sequence), rather than having to put that code in the called function or to use a call back function to deal with the nodes.